# Extract JSON object column to multiple columns in Spark using Java

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I'm using Java 11 with Spark 3.3.0. Let's say I have a DataFrame with two columns, `id` (a string identifier) and `properties` (a string containing a single JSON object, e.g. `{"foo":123,"bar":"test"}`).

How can I "explode" all the name-value pairs of the properties object into multiple columns, e.g. `id`, `foo`, `bar`.

I've seen solutions using `select()`. But then I would have to take care to select the existing columns, wouldn't I? Is there a simpler way to simply add additional columns as needed in one command?

I know I can add a single column at a time if I already know what properties to expect, like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("foo", get_json_object(col("properties"), "$.foo"))
df = df.withColumn("bar", get_json_object(col("properties"), "$.bar"))
```

Is there a way to add all the columns necessary for the properties JSON object in the `properties` column in one fell swoop, even without knowing ahead of time what properties will be in each JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamically the properties of your JSON object as Dataset columns in Java 11 and Spark 3.3.0 as below:

```
ds = ds.select("*", "properties.*");
```

Input:

```
+---+---+------------+
|id |col|properties  |
+---+---+------------+
|1  |foo|{123, null} |
|2  |bar|{456, test2}|
+---+---+------------+
```

Output:

```
+---+---+------------+---+-----+
| id|col|  properties|foo|  bar|
+---+---+------------+---+-----+
|  1|foo| {123, null}|123| null|
|  2|bar|{456, test2}|456|test2|
+---+---+------------+---+-----+
```

Hope this is what you need, good luck!

Comment: That gives me `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: 'List(properties)'`.